# Fixed background cover becomes zoomed in mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile, interface

I'm using a fixed background cover for my website here: http://www.datisdesign.com

Every page has a big header image, but in small devices such as mobiles, the cover image becomes so large. I want to make it smaller in mobile devices.

This the code that I'm using:

```
#takelessons {
    background: url(../img/portfolio/takelessons-intro.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
}
```

[image: Normal view]

[image: Mobile view]

Comment: tried `background-size:contain`? or `background-size:auto`?

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem by limiting the capability to the large tablet screen size.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    #parallax {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :)

Add the below to your style...

```
background-size:100%;
width:100%;
```

I hope this helps

Comment: didn't work here, caused multiple images instead of just the one. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one out

```
background: url(image.format) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if `background-size: cover` is used with `background-attachment: fixed` it causes this issue on mobile.

Changing from 'fixed' to 'scroll' fixes it.

In my case I used Javascript for my parallax effect so I was able to update the equation to account for the different background behavior.