# Jumbotron image works fine on desktop, on mobile the image is blown up and I can't get it to resize

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I've added a jumbotron image that as you scroll is fixed and you get a lovely snippet of the image. This works fine on desktop, but once I view the page on a mobile the image will not fit into the space available, all you see is a small corner of the image and very pixelated.

I have tried using a max-width media query, different margins, padding and image options (such as background-size/repeat/attachment) and everything else the internet and this forum has suggested. However, the image just won't resize to fit my much smaller container space.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

HTML

```
<!--jumbotron midway-->
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid midway">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.midway {
    background-image: url(Images/loneTree.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    padding: 150px;
    margin:0;
}
```

Below is the image on desktop VV

[image: Image on desktop - clear]

Below is the image on mobile - the image has become a grey blob VV

[image: image on mobile - a grey blob]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed background cover becomes zoomed in mobile view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838718/fixed-background-cover-becomes-zoomed-in-mobile-view)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately not - the image became scaled correctly but I was left with grey boxes top and bottom of the image as I scrolled past them.